# Declination of adjective when the adjective is already ended with -en

Tags: adjective-ending

I have notice there are some usage of "im vergangen Jahr", a list of examples can be found [here](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/im+vergangen+jahr.html). But I think grammatically it should be "im vergangenen Jahr" (which is also written often). My question is that, is that a general mistake or a purposeful simplification of the adjective ending, when the end is `-en`.

One of the examples is the following sentence from a [document](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/pdfs/news/public/focus/20100630FCS77242/20100630FCS77242_de.pdf) of European Parliament:

> Leider ist im **vergangen** Jahr die Zahl der Menschen, denen wir helfen konnten in ihre Heimat zurückzukehren, stark zurückgegangen, insbesondere aufgrund der Situation in Afghanistan im Südsudan und in der Demokratischen Republik Kongo.

Comment: Judging from the links, this appears to be Swiss dialect, although this is just a guess. At least in standard German this feels wrong and you are correct, it should be *im vergangenen Jahr*.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please include (copy'paste) relevant quotes from the linked source. That makes it easier.

Comment: Looking at the widespread sources I'm afraid, that this is a consequence of  simple spelling checkers which do not consider grammar: No highlight, no correction.

Comment: Isn't there also a comma missing after *konnten*, or am I just too old for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong: "Im vergangen Jahr"
Correct: "Im vergangen**en** Jahr"

Also:

> die gefahren**en** Kilometer
>   die getragen**en** Socken
>   die gebraten**en** Schweine
>   die empfangen**en** Geschenke
>   die gelesen**en** Bücher
>   die vergessen**en** Schulfreunde
>   die erschrocken**en** Kinder
>   die gebogen**en** Stäbe
>   die verloren**en** Seelen
>   die begonnen**en** Aufsätze
>   die verziehen**en** Sünden
>   die übertrieben**en** Bewegungen
>   etc.

I didn't find any exception. You always have to add *-en*.

Btw: Almost all words that behave like adjectives and end with -en are not genuine adjectives but participles. Your word *vergangen* is a good example,  *verdorben* is another:

- verb:

  - Das Jahr vergeht. Der Käse verdirbt. (Präsens)
  - Das Jahr wird vergehen. Der Käse wird verderben. (Futur I)
  - Das Jahr ist vergangen. Der Käse ist verdorben. (Perfekt)
- participle used like an adjective:

  - Das vergangene Jahr war schön. Der verdorbene Käse stinkt. (attribute usage)
  - Das Jahr ist vergangen. Der Käse ist verdorben. (predicative usage)
  - (--) Der Käse riecht verdorben. (adverbial usage)

(I didn't find an example für adverbial usage of *vergangen*.)

But there are also genuine Adjectives that end with -en:

- cremefarben (ockerfarben, ...)

  > die cremefarben**en** Hemden
- trocken

  > die trocken**en** Tücher

As you see, they also behave in the same way.